# How to determine if Binary Tree is BST

Tags: c#, data-structures, tree, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I am trying to figure out a logic to determine if Binary Tree is BST. I want to use the inorder approach and I don't want to use an extra array to store all incoming values as we know that Inorder should be in sorted order. I want to check the incoming value w/o having to store it in an array. Below is my attempt which is not working.

```
   public bool CheckBST(BstNode root)
        {
            BstNode prev = new BstNode(Int32.MinValue);
            if (root == null)
                return true;
            if (root.left != null)
            {
                return CheckBST(root.left);
            }
            if (prev != null && prev.data >= root.data) // means data  is not sorted hence NOT   BST
                return false;
            prev = root;
            if(root.right!=null)
            {
                return CheckBST(root.right);
            }
            return true;
        }
```

Comment: *Carefully* define what a BST is.  Once you have a careful, precise definition, then you can write code which clearly and simply determines if the requirements are met or not.

Answer (score 4):

Given a binary tree, following determines if it is a valid binary search tree (BST).

- The left subtree of a node contains only nodes with keys less than
  the node's key.
- The right subtree of a node contains only nodes with keys greater
  than the node's key.
- Both the left and right subtrees must also be binary search trees.

Let's see below example:

[image]

If you see the above Binary Tree is a BST.

Now let's see another example :

[image]

The root node's value is 5 but its right child's value is 4 which does not satisfy the condition mentioned above. So the given tree is not a BST.

**Solution Code:**

Given that the TreeNode is defined as

```
public class TreeNode 
{
    public int Val { get; set; }
    public TreeNode Left { get; set; }
    public TreeNode Right { get; set; }
    public TreeNode(int x) { this.Val = x; }
}
```

The code to check the validation is

```
public bool IsValidBST(TreeNode root) 
{
    return IsValidBST(root, int.MinValue, int.MaxValue);
}

private bool IsValidBST(TreeNode root, int minValue, int maxValue)
{
    if (root == null)
    {
        return true;
    }

    int nodeValue = root.Val;
    if (nodeValue < minValue || nodeValue > maxValue)
    {
        return false;
    }

    return IsValidBST(root.Left, minValue, nodeValue - 1) && IsValidBST(root.Right, nodeValue + 1, maxValue);
}
```

Now the `IsValidBST` can be invoked with root node

```
 bool isValidBST = IsValidBST(rootNode);
```

Answer (score 0):

So usually in a BST there are three things in each node. That is the data, and the two pointers left and right. If there are more than two pointers available in any node then it is not a BST. It is probably best to determine at the level of the node if it there are more pointers than there should be. You would be wasting time and resources by searching the tree.

Here is a good way to go about doing it https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/a-program-to-check-if-a-binary-tree-is-bst-or-not/

Comment: Question says given tree is Binary Tree

Answer (score 0):

You can't initilaze the `prev` everytime in `CheckBST`. You can make the `prev` global. Also I have made the `prev` as type `integer`.

```
int prev = Int32.MinValue; //made this global and integer type

public bool CheckBST(BstNode root) {
 if (root == null)
  return true;
 bool isLeftBST = CheckBST(root.left);
 if (isLeftBST == false) return false;

 if (prev != Int32.MinValue && prev >= root.data) // means data  is not sorted hence NOT   BST
  return false;

 prev = root.data; //mark the prev before traversing the right subtree

 return isLeftBST && CheckBST(root.right);

}
```

Ignore the syntax problems, if any. I tried more of a pseudo code.

Ofcourse there are other ways to solve this problem as well. Like keeping track of  min and max value so far (in @user1672994 answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you could make `CheckBST` return the range (min, max) of the BST being checked, then the following recursive function shall do:

```
// Defines the return value that represents BST check failure.
const pair<int, int> kCheckFailed(Int32.MaxValue, Int32.MinValue);

pair<int, int> CheckBST(const BstNode& curr)
{
  pair<int, int> left_ret(curr.value, curr.value);
  pair<int, int> right_ret(curr.value, curr.value);

  // Makes sure the left subtree, if any, is a BST, and its max
  // (`left_ret.second`) is no greater than `curr.value`
  if (curr.left) {
    left_ret = CheckBST(*curr.left);
    if (left_ret == kCheckFailed || left_ret.second > curr.value)
      return kCheckFailed;
  }

  // Makes sure the right subtree, if any, is a BST, and its min
  // (`right_ret.first`) is not less than `curr.value`.
  if (curr.right) {
    right_ret = CheckBST(*curr.right);
    if (right_ret == kCheckFailed || right_ret.first < curr.value)
      return kCheckFailed;
  }

  // Returns range by combining min of left subtree and max of right subtree.
  return make_pair(left_ret.first, right_ret.second);
}
```

Note that `CheckBST` takes a (sub)tree root by reference to ensure the node (`curr`) is always valid. However, `curr.left` or `curr.right` may still be NULL, in which cases, the corresponding min or max values, respectively, are just `curr.value`, as initialized to both `ret_left` and `ret_right`.

Answer (score 0):

- Recursive with time complexity of *O(1)*.
- Remove the commented our lines to see how it gets called.
- For the first call pass `isBST(root, null, null)`.

  ```
  public bool isBST(Node root, Node l, Node r)
  {
          // Console.WriteLine($"Processing: isBST({root?.data}, {l?.data}, {r?.data})");
          if (root == null) return true;

          if (l != null && root.data <= l.data) return false;

          if (r != null && root.data >= r.data) return false;

          // Console.WriteLine($"isBST({root?.left?.data}, {l}, {root?.data}) && isBST({root?.right?.data}, {root?.data}, {r?.data})");
          return isBST(root.left, l, root) && isBST(root.right, root, r);
  }
  ```

Answer (score -1):

You dont need **prev**.

1. Check recursively that max(left) is less than or equal root.
2. Check recursively that min(right) if greater than root.
3. Check if the left is BST.
4. Check if the right is BST.

Of course, check on nulls where needed.

Comment: Check that left *subtree* is less than (or equal?) to root. It isn't enough that the immediate left child node is less than the root, the whole left subtree has to be, which, as long as you independently verify that the left subtree is also a BST you can check by going to the left childnode and then to the ultimate right child of that, if that child node is less than (or equal to?) the root, then this condition is satisfied.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen: NO. I mean left and right immediate CHILDREN. "the whole left subtree has to be" - sure, this is step 3. But BEFORE you check the left and the right subtrees (which make take huge time if there are millions of elements) first you should check the immediate left and right children (steps 1 and 2). If this condition is not true "left <= root < right", it makes no sense to check the left and the right subtrees. Only if this condition is true, you check the subtrees, steps 3 and 4. If you voted down, please consider reverting it :)

Comment: Left child can be a BST By itself, but still have nodes greater than the "root", it still seems your step-by-step is missing a step or two.

Comment: Oh, you are right. Comparing of the immediate nodes may improve the performance, but is no sufficient. Actually we should compare following: "max(left) <= root < min(right)".